# Pervasive select max date selects the minimum date

Tags: pervasive-sql

Can someone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
SELECT MAX(LNK_DATE), LNK_LINK
FROM ISLINKS
WHERE "ORDERNUM" = 140420
GROUP BY LNK_LINK
```

This returns the lowest date value for 2 records. I'm looking for the max date. What am I missing?

Comment: What version of Pervasive?  
How many records match that ORDERNUM?  What other Date Values are they? 
Is the LNK_DATE field a Date datatype or something else?  
What are the results of your query and your query without the MAX (but still showing the date)?

Comment: Hi Mirtheil. Thanks for looking. THis is v10.2 I believe. The recordset contains 2 but may contain more than that; maybe 10 total? The results of the query are the same however I query. However, if I **only** query for the max date, I will get the right result. When I add in the `LNK_LINK`, it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm guessing your LNK_LINK value is different when the ORDERNUM is the same.

Comment: Yes, the LNK_LINK value is different. It's essentially a rev number but the rest of the link is identical. But yes, different none the less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using PSQL v11 but I'm sure it's the same across most versions.

Using the following SQL, I get the correct (max date) results when the LNK_LINK field is the same.  If it is different between the two records, the engine will treat it as different records and display them when the `GROUP BY` is used.  Here's the SQL I used:

```
create table SO_ISLINKS (lnk_Date date, ORDERNUM int, lnk_link char(100))#
insert into SO_ISLINKS values ('2021-01-28', 140420, 'link1')#
insert into SO_ISLINKS values ('2021-01-15', 140420, 'link1')#
insert into SO_ISLINKS values ('2021-01-25', 140420, 'link2')#
insert into SO_ISLINKS values ('2021-01-23', 140420, 'link3')#
insert into SO_ISLINKS values ('2021-01-01', 140421, 'link4')#
SELECT MAX(LNK_DATE), LNK_LINK
FROM SO_ISLINKS
WHERE "ORDERNUM" = 140420
GROUP BY LNK_LINK
```

This returns:

```
    EXPR_1   lnk_link                                                                                            
==========   ==========
 1/28/2021   link1                                                                                               
 1/25/2021   link2                                                                                               
 1/23/2021   link3
```

When LNK_LINK is the same (link1) in my query, it shows only the one Date (1/28/2021).
If you take the LNK_LINK out of the query, it should show the Max Date across all records.

Comment: Thank you Mirtheil. I think I have it now.